# Dynamic SQL to calculate colums without knowing their number

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that can have any number of fields starting with either `aaa_` or `bbb_` prefix - lets call them *weight columns*. And additionally I have a `value` column.

I would like to add calculated fields (number matches the number of *weight colums*) that multiplies all of the weight column values column by column with the *value* column.

For a fixed number of fields it would look like this:

```sql
SELECT [Id]
    ,[aaa_1]
    ,[bbb_1]
    ,[value]
    ,[aaa_1] * [value] AS [aaa_1_value]
    ,[bbb_1] * [value] AS [bbb_1_value]
FROM myTable
```

But as weights can be a large number and changing, I cannot do this in a static way.

I have managed to get the weight fields like this:

```sql
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)
SET @sql = 'SELECT [Id]
      ,[value] '
SELECT @sql = @sql + '[' + COLUMN_NAME +'],'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'myTable'   
    AND (COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'aaa_%' OR COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'bbb_%')
SET @sql = @sql + ' 1 FROM myTable'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

How can I add the multiplication dynamically?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

Comment: the syntax to add a calculated column is: alter table add calcColumn AS someCol * someOtherCol. So, all you need is to generate a number of such strings and then execute them. You already found how to get the actual column names, the rest should be easy

Comment: Perhaps the problem is the design, and instead of a bunch of `aaa_` and `bbb_` columns you should have a different table with a column for the `aaa`/`bbb` value and another for the value you have in your current table. Then you can always have a `VIEW` that `JOIN`s the tables together and have a separate *row* for each value that multiples `aaa` by `value`.

Comment: How can you not know how many columns are in your table?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The table is created with a stored procedure using a parameter table that is maintained by the business. I.e they can add columns to that table should they require another metric using MDS. Hence the problem of dynamic column numbers.

Comment: Do you want to actually add a computed column to the table, or just create a `SELECT` statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just build it the same way you build the other columns

- `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` is for compatibility only. Use `sys.columns` instead.
- Instead of concatenating `[]`, use `QUOTENAME` for correct quoting.
- Do not use `@var = @var +` for aggregation, it has undefined behaviour. Use `STRING_AGG` instead.

```sql
DECLARE
  @sql nvarchar(max),
  @cols1 nvarchar(max),
  @cols2 nvarchar(max);

SELECT

  @cols1 = STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(c.name), ',
  '),

  @cols2 = STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(c.name) + ' * value AS ' + QUOTENAME(c.name + '_value'), ',
  ')

FROM sys.columns c
JOIN sys.tables t ON t.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE t.name = 'myTable'   
  AND (c.name LIKE 'aaa_%' OR c.name LIKE 'bbb_%');

SET @sql = '
SELECT
  Id,
  ' + @cols1 + '
  value,
  ' + @cols2 + '
FROM myTable;
';

PRINT @sql;   -- your friend

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```